# Same site cookie issue odoo 11

Tags: cookies, payment-gateway, odoo-11, werkzeug, samesite

Edition: enterprise
Version: 11.0

What are the steps to reproduce your issue?

Made payment to a payment gateway and redirected back to Odoo after payment

What is currently happening?

The entire Cookie is blank and cleared.

What are you expecting to happen?

Cookie to contain details of session & other auth details

Note: For faster turnaround, please share as much detail as you can. Tell us which Menu sequences you follow. Attach screenshots. Share a video.

So when we checked in much detail we found out that this issue seems to be happening on newer browsers of google chrome which could be due to the fact of same site cookie changes how can we overcome this?

I had a look and it seems like werkzeug future versions have this fixed but how do we fix it on older versions of the same like odoo11ENT. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: this issue is open at odoo git repo as well, if anyone can find the answer that would be appreciated..

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/51065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also facing this issue, after searching in odoo code I found  save_session=False in the controller, which worked for me.

So just add  save_session=False in the controller

this is the controller for the reference :

@http.route('/payment/takepayment/response', type='http', auth='public', csrf=False, save_session=False)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).